# When I try to run "sudo apt-get install uuid-dev" I get the following error

Tags: configuration, asterisk

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 uuid-dev : Depends: libuuid1 (= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update`  first ?

Comment: yes to  download package information from  configure sources.